# Outcast Girl, power to kill and/or set people on fire with a glance, world is extremely hot, kind of scary, might include dragons

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

This is a book that impacted and scared me a lot as a kid, but I only have the vaguest memories except a few points that stick out. I'm also a little suspicious I might be conflating two books I read around the same time... I'm pretty sure I actually listened to this as an audiobook (on cd) rented from my local library sometime between 2004- 2007, but I also think it wasn't a brand new release- maybe something from 80s or early 90s.

I remember the main character was a girl who was outcast from society, because she had the power to kill people by looking at them. Or perhaps the other people in her society just accused her of having this power. I think she lived in a small village with a dystopian atmosphere. I also remember fire being a big theme in the book, maybe she could set people on fire by looking at them but I'm not totally sure. I think eventually she meets someone else with similar powers. I believe the fantasy world this takes place in had a very hot climate. I also think there may have been a tree on the cover?

I also feel at some point dragons might come into play, although I can't remember a lot of details about when or how. Overall I remember the book having quite a serious tone given the content. I think I would have read this when I was about 8 or 9ish.. I guess it was a middle grade/ young adult book. I know it seems a little dark for middle grade,  but I swear it WAS dark.